# Upgrade a VS2010 ASP.NET 3.5 Entity Framework project to EF 4.0?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, frameworks, entity

How do I upgrade an existing VS2010 ASP.Net 3.5 project from Entity Framework 3.5 to Entity Framework 4.0?

Do I:

- Change the references?
- Change the target framework?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the target framework, then update your code for any new errors. :)

> Solution explorer > right click your
>   solution name > properties >
>   application tab > target framework

Backup your Entity model first, just in case the designer decides to break something (it shouldn't.)

Comment: Thankyou! Be great if this was documented.

Comment: Agreed. All I can find on it is this this MSDN thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/693ffa9d-5d58-4056-9787-023f905fb2e8

Answer (score 1):

if you change you target framework you will see this message on your Output window

> The namespaces in the storage, conceptual, and mapping sections of the .edmx files in the project [Your Project] were successfully updated to match the project's targeted .NET framework.

This have worked for me.